# Confirmatory factor analysis using SEM: What do we do with items with zero variance?

Tags: variance, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

When I run my analysis with items with zero variance, `sem` in `R` would throw up a warning saying that items with zero variance exist. I then move on to remove these from the analysis. My question is:

1. Are there any other ways of resolving this problem besides removing the items perhaps like adding a very small amount of jitter?
2. What literature is there to justify such a procedure? (I have searched but have not come up with anything. I am guessing either this is not a common problem or the solution is too obvious.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you should remove the item and use the remaining items to estimate your latent variable in the measurement model.  Items with no variance add no information and will make the correlation matrix blow up.

You can get prune them using something like this:

```
library(psych)
descriptives <- describe(data)
good_variables <- which(descriptives$range != 0)
data <- data[,good_variables]
```

Comment: Thanks. What about items with very low variance? How do we gauge what is low variance and should we also remove them?

Comment: And also, do you have any references on this?

Comment: If you remove the items with no variance does your model work?  If you could post some more details, we could help troubleshoot.  Generally, as long as an item has variance, `lavaan` and `sem` will work.  However, conceptually, items with restriction of range can be problematic.  I don't have any references off-hand, but there is a section in Loehlin, J. C. (2003) that I will find and post tomorrow that discusses the problem.  Also, have you tried using `score.items()` to examine the reliability of the item with the scale?  Items with reduced range may not correlate with your factor well.

Comment: ok thanks much! I have the Loehlin but didn't find anywhere where he addressed this issue. I'll post my data in another question. I'll make it as answered for now but would appreciate if you could supplement with the reference.